# How to dedupe an excel file based on multiple conditions in python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, duplicates

I have an Excel file ([attached here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0N-G5EzKChlR2hhRUxPbGJTdUU)). I have to dedupe it against two or more duplicate ids.
Criteria for deduping is based on multiple factors.

1. Id
2. Type
3. Time

Now, the process I follow manually to dedupe is:

1. I sort id in Ascending order.
2. I set Attribute for every id starting with t as tid.
3. I put xid for every [id] in id column. I sometimes leave a blank for one id if there are duplicate [id](if dates are same for two consecutive [id]).
4. For every duplicate id, I first check Type if it is Tea or Coffee. If one is coffee and other is tea we will always prefer coffee and set the attribute as "No" for tea. We can get more than 2 duplicates, so, we have to set "No" for all the tea for same IDs. If we get two coffee and one tea for same IDs then we will keep the latest one based on time.
5. If the duplicate ids have the same type then we will look at dates and set the attribute as "No" for older dates. If dates are same then we will keep one and set Attribute as "No" for others. The IDs can be more than two but the process will be same.

What I want to do is:

1. Set attribute as tid for IDs starting with t.
2. Set attribute as xid for IDs having [].
3. Set No in attribute if two or more IDs are duplicate based on certain conditions:

   - Coffee should be preferred over tea. If we have tea and coffee in
     type for duplicate ids, we put No in attribute against every tea for
     every duplicate ID.
   - In case we have one tea and two or more coffee for every duplicate ID
     then we will set No against remaining coffees based on the time(IDs
     with older timestamps should be No.)
   - If we have the same Type for every duplicate ID then whichever ID is
     latest according to time should be kept and for all others attributes
     should be No.
   - If we have same dates and same types for all duplicate IDs then we
     will just randomly set No against all except one.

**Note:**

- Duplicate one, two and three are there for us to easily just filter out based on color and then dedupe.They based on Excel formulas: (Duplicate 1=(=IF(B2=B3,1,""), Duplicate2=(=IF(C1=1,1,""), Duplicate3=(=IF(SUM(C2:D2) >=1,1,""))
- We can't delete rows.
- I can't figure out any code for this and this is the blocker for me in a key automation process.
- There are No/xid/tid in the attribute column in attached file for reference.

**Important Question:**
 - Is it even possible or feasible to do with python?

Answer (score 0):

I dont't know if I get your question right thus I will provide a few different ways.

If you want to remove all rows which contain the same values for id,Type  and Time this could be done with:

```
frame=pd.read_excel(io=r"D:\xxxxxx\test.xlsx")
df=pd.DataFrame(frame)
drop_dup=df.drop_duplicates(subset=("id","Type","Time"))
print(drop_dup)
```

which yields:

```
              id  Duplicate 1  Duplicate 2  Total Duplicates  \
0            121349100          NaN          NaN               NaN   
1            121350610          NaN          NaN               NaN   
2            124426041          NaN          NaN               NaN   
3            124436734          NaN          NaN               NaN   
4            124451775          1.0          NaN               1.0   
5            124451775          1.0          1.0               1.0   
7            124463136          NaN          NaN               NaN   
8            124463568          NaN          NaN               NaN   
9            124469946          NaN          NaN               NaN   
10           124474373          NaN          NaN               NaN   

....
                  Time    Type Attribute  
0  2017-04-19 18:08:00     Tea       NaN  
1  2017-04-19 18:08:00     Tea       NaN  
2  2017-05-05 12:21:00     Tea       NaN  
3  2017-04-25 15:20:00  Coffee       NaN  
4  2017-04-05 21:04:00  Coffee        No  
5  2017-06-05 07:38:00     Tea        No  
7  2017-06-05 05:40:00  Coffee       NaN  
8  2017-09-04 23:12:00     Tea       NaN  
9  2017-04-24 07:48:00     Tea       NaN  
10 2017-07-05 23:39:00  Coffee       NaN  
....
[77 rows x 7 columns]
```

This means there are 7 rows which have exactly the same Type, id and Time.
If you want to drop rows which are exactly the same (all columns are incorporated) this will yield the desired result:

```
df=df.drop_duplicates()
```

Furthermore:

```
dup=df.duplicated(subset=("id","Type","Time"))
```

returns a True/False array which indicates if rows are duplicates or not

```
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6      True
7     False
```

If you want to know which single values of your DataFrame are duplicates use:

```
dupl_val=df.apply(pd.Series.duplicated,axis=1)

       id  Duplicate 1  Duplicate 2  Total Duplicates   Time   Type  Attribute
0   False        False        False             False  False  False      False
1   False        False        False             False  False  False      False
2   False        False        False             False  False  False      False
3   False        False        False             False  False  False      False
4   False        False        False              True  False  False      False
5   False        False         True              True  False  False      False
6   False        False        False              True  False  False      False
```

The reason for calling pd.Series.duplicated is that this method is applied to the axis 1 of the DataFrame which means to each single DataFrame column. A DataFrame column is a Pandas Series object.

If you don't want to delete the rows but just indicate which values are duplicates use:

```
dupl_val=df.apply(pd.Series.duplicated,axis=1)
df=df.where(~dupl_val,"duplicate")
print(df)


                    id Duplicate 1 Duplicate 2 Total Duplicates  \
0            121349100         NaN         NaN              NaN   
1            121350610         NaN         NaN              NaN   
2            124426041         NaN         NaN              NaN   
3            124436734         NaN         NaN              NaN   
4            124451775           1         NaN        duplicate   
5            124451775           1   duplicate        duplicate   
6            124451775         NaN           1        duplicate     

                  Time    Type Attribute  
0  2017-04-19 18:08:00     Tea       NaN  
1  2017-04-19 18:08:00     Tea       NaN  
2  2017-05-05 12:21:00     Tea       NaN  
3  2017-04-25 15:20:00  Coffee       NaN  
4  2017-04-05 21:04:00  Coffee        No  
5  2017-06-05 07:38:00     Tea        No  
6  2017-04-05 21:04:00  Coffee       NaN
```

**EDIT:**
If you just want to set the Attribute column to a special value (I have chosen "duplicate") if "id","Type","Time" values within a row are duplicates of another row and don't want to change the values of the remaining columns, this code should deliver the desired result:

```
frame=pd.read_excel(io=r"D:\xxxxx\test.xlsx")
df=pd.DataFrame(frame)


dup=df.duplicated(subset=("id","Type","Time"))

duplicate="duplicate"

for i in range(len(dup)):
    if dup[i]==True:
        df.loc[i,"Attribute"]=duplicate

print(df)

                    id  Duplicate 1  Duplicate 2  Total Duplicates  \
0            121349100          NaN          NaN               NaN   
1            121350610          NaN          NaN               NaN   
2            124426041          NaN          NaN               NaN   
3            124436734          NaN          NaN               NaN   
4            124451775          1.0          NaN               1.0   
5            124451775          1.0          1.0               1.0   
6            124451775          NaN          1.0               1.0   
7            124463136          NaN          NaN               NaN   
                  Time    Type  Attribute  
0  2017-04-19 18:08:00     Tea        NaN  
1  2017-04-19 18:08:00     Tea        NaN  
2  2017-05-05 12:21:00     Tea        NaN  
3  2017-04-25 15:20:00  Coffee        NaN  
4  2017-04-05 21:04:00  Coffee         No  
5  2017-06-05 07:38:00     Tea         No  
6  2017-04-05 21:04:00  Coffee  duplicate 
7  2017-06-05 05:40:00  Coffee        NaN  

[85 rows x 7 columns]
```

You can see, that row 6 (= row 8 in the original excel file) contains the first duplicate. In this case this is a duplicate of row number 6 in the excel file.

**EDIT 2**

In my second edit the code now will mark ALL duplicates (also the first) as "duplicates". Also the code does no longer seach for all three columns (id,Time,Type) but either for (id and Time) OR (id and Type) OR (Time and Type). Thus all combinations of these three coumns

```
dup=[df.duplicated(subset=(i),keep=False) for i in [("id","Type"),("id","Time"),("Time","Type")]]
duplicate="duplicate"

for i in range(len(dup)):
    for j in range(len(dup[i])):
        if dup[i][j]==True:
            df.loc[j,"Attribute"]=duplicate


print(df)
```

|

```
       id  Duplicate 1  Duplicate 2  Total Duplicates  \
0            121349100          NaN          NaN               NaN   
1            121350610          NaN          NaN               NaN   
2            124426041          NaN          NaN               NaN   
3            124436734          NaN          NaN               NaN   
4            124451775          1.0          NaN               1.0   
5            124451775          1.0          1.0               1.0   
6            124451775          NaN          1.0               1.0   
              Time    Type  Attribute  
0  2017-04-19 18:08:00     Tea  duplicate  
1  2017-04-19 18:08:00     Tea  duplicate  
2  2017-05-05 12:21:00     Tea        NaN  
3  2017-04-25 15:20:00  Coffee        NaN  
4  2017-04-05 21:04:00  Coffee  duplicate  
5  2017-06-05 07:38:00     Tea         No  
6  2017-04-05 21:04:00  Coffee  duplicate
```

For more inforations about this functions read: [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), [duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) for both, Series and DataFrames (the main difference is that for Series, the functions are applied to single values and for DataFrames they are applied to rows respectively to rows of specified columns)

Comment: the problem is I want to get output in attribute column and I don't want to do any changes to the existing columns.

Comment: it did work partially, and I also figured it out till this point. Issues i am having are: 1) When there are more than two duplicates, the code works on just one and return value against just one of the duplicates. What I want is the value should be against two duplicates and should meet the conditions.2) It also shows up **Duplicate** against wrong value. I need it to show duplicate against ID with an older date.

Comment: @PyNoob 1. The code reurns "duplicate" in the Attribure column if the values in the rows (id,Time,Type) have be seen once before. This also means that the first row is not marked as duplicate but the second, third and so on. Do you also want that the first line (the first occurence of the values is marked as duplicate)? 2. At the moment the code only marks duplicated if the values in thr id. Type and Time column are the same. Do I get it right, thtat you also want to mark it as duplicate if either id, Time or Type (means one of them) are duplicates?

Comment: In my second edit the code now will mark ALL duplicates (also the first) as dupicates. Also the code does no longer seach for all three columns (id,TIme,Type) but either for "id" OR (id and Time) OR for (id and Type).

Comment: No, I really appreciate what you are doing but you might look at the question again which I edited for better understanding. @2Obe